# Why MS Excel doesnt render CSV file correctly

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

I have a CSV file with following contents:

```
timestamp, post_header, post_content
2021-12-05 16:11:31.138993,Pista Software | Test,"...<long multiline text>..."
2021-12-05 16:11:31.138993,Crap AI| Reopen,"...<long multiline text>..."
```

When I opened this in MS Excel, it gets rendered as follows:

[image]

When I open on becsv.com, it gets rendered as follows:

[image]

How can I make MS Excel render in same

Comment: Try to format the Timestamp column as time or date and see if Excel recognize your data

Comment: Yes, I was generating those timestamps on my own in python. So, reformatting those datetime  as`datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')` made trick. But I was guessing why it did not separate using comma earlier.

Comment: same very annoying issue! not solved with the comment above. Excel only shows minutes and seconds, unless clicking the cell.

Answer (score 0):

You might try putting quotes around your date/timestamp.  Excel is looking at your date/timestamp and assuming its own formatting style.  If you put quotes around it, Excel will assume it is text and keep that format that you have given it.